# Path Animation Evaluation Time

Tags: path

I want to animate a bone along a curve and I'm mising some information about evaluation time, I 'd like to have the bone move at a range of 0.32m/50frames and I want help with the curve's generator modifier. I would assume that the y-axis in this case is in meters but I'm wrong. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: So maybe create a curve that is 10 units long and in the Generator choose x^1 = 0.66 which will bring the object at 3.2 units?

Comment: Thank you! If it;s not much trouble could you explain how you ended up with that value?

Comment: I just tweaked the value until the Path Animation > Evaluation Time value reached 32 (with Frames being 100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a curve that is 10 units long, in the *Generator* modifier choose x^1 = 0.66 which will bring the object at 3.2 units at frame 50:

[image]